# CAST function/ padding executes sucessfully but does not show up in table results

Tags: sql-server

I have used the following CAST function, to change from int to varchar

```
SELECT Genre,
       GenreUpdated = LEFT(REPLICATE('x',12) + CAST(Genre AS VARCHAR (23)),23)
FROM Artists
```

The query executed successfully and the results are as follows;

```
    Genre       GenreUpdated
1   Pop         xxxxxxxxxxxxPop
2   Pop         xxxxxxxxxxxxPop
3   Grunge      xxxxxxxxxxxxGrunge
4   Alternative xxxxxxxxxxxxAlternative
5   Soul        xxxxxxxxxxxxSoul
```

However when I want to retrieve the table by using the code `SELECT * FROM Artists`, I get the following;

```
    Artist                  Genre       Country     GenreUpdated
1   The Beatles             Pop         UK          Pop
2   The Beach Boys          Pop         USA         Pop
3   Nirvana                 Grunge      USA         Grunge
4   The Velvet Underground  Alternative USA         Alternative
5   Marvin Gaye             Soul        USA         Soul
```

I want the table column "GenreUpdated" to look the same as above, as in include all the x characters, including the padding.

I did try to use the `INSERT` function, to include the padding as follows;

```
INSERT INTO Artists (GenreUpdated)
SELECT REPLICATE ('x',23 - DATALENGTH(GenreUpdated)) + GenreUpdated AS 'Varchar Column'
FROM Artists
```

However this gives me the error message, "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Artist', table 'BestAlbums2.dbo.Artists'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails". This error comes up despite my column properties being varchar(23) null.

Can anyone help and advise me of where I am going wrong please?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you permanently want to change the data in the column `GenreUpdated` you need to use an `update` statement.

`INSERT` adds new data which is not what you want to do; you want to use `UPDATE` which changes existing data.

```
UPDATE Artists
SET GenreUpdated = LEFT(REPLICATE('x',12) + CAST(Genre AS VARCHAR(23)),23)
```

As the data in `GenreUpdated` depends on `Genre` you should consider not storing it at all, but instead use a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which would return the data in the desired format, but wouldn't need updating if the `Genre` column changes. You can add it by using the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE artists 
ADD GenreUpdatedComputed AS LEFT(REPLICATE('x',12) + CAST(Genre AS VARCHAR(23)),23)
```

Comment: Thank you, when I see your answer and your explanation, I was obviously making a basic error. Too much staring at it and retrying my code, to realize my basic error. Hopefully I won't make that mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Artists
SET
GenreUpdated = LEFT(REPLICATE('x',12) + CAST(Genre AS VARCHAR (23)),23)
```